# Converting Mesh to curves, adding depth makes the mesh overlap

Tags: modeling

I have a mesh which I'm converting to a curve. When I add some depth, the mesh points seem to be overlapping rather been one solid object. Even with minimal depth, the mesh still seems to be separate from each other

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A control point on a curve can only be in one of two categories: being either 1. an endpoint connected to one curve segment or being 2. an inner point connecting two curve segments. A control point can never be connected to more than two curve segments. Which means, they do not **seem** as if they are separate from each other, they **are** separate. A curve can never fork into two different directions from one control point.